# Problems catching unidecoder exceptions

Tags: ruby, unidecoder

I'm trying out the unidecoder gem and it's giving me problems with some strings:

```
require 'unidecoder'
str = "\u00A3"
str.to_ascii
```

> #: (C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unidecoder-1.1.1/lib/unidecoder/data/x00.yml):
>   found unknown escape character while parsing a quote d scalar at line
>   2 column 3
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in`parse_stream'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:151:in `parse'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:127:in`load'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:297:in `block in load_file'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:297:in`open'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:297:in `load_file'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unidecoder-1.1.1/lib/unidecoder.rb:8:in`
>   block in '
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unidecoder-1.1.1/lib/unidecoder.rb:78:in
>   `yield'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unidecoder-1.1.1/lib/unidecoder.rb:78:in`
>   default'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unidecoder-1.1.1/lib/unidecoder.rb:78:in
>   `decode_char'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unidecoder-1.1.1/lib/unidecoder.rb:39:in`
>   block in decode'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unidecoder-1.1.1/lib/unidecoder.rb:37:in
>   `gsub'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unidecoder-1.1.1/lib/unidecoder.rb:37:in`
>   decode'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unidecoder-1.1.1/lib/unidecoder.rb:16:in
>   `to_ascii'
>           from (irb):21
>           from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in`'>>

What's worse, I can't catch the error by doing:

```
foo = str.to_ascii rescue 'x'
```

Does anyone know what's happening here?

Comment: What’s your current system `LOCALE`? Regarding rescueing: [rescue clause with no parameter list, the parameter defaults to StandardError](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_exceptions.html); it looks like `unidecoder` raises kinda other exception, but the stacktrace seems to be incomplete (it should show the exception type.)

Comment: @mudasobwa - I think that must be it. I was under the impression that rescue without a parameter caught everything. If you want to put it in an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[rescue clause with no parameter list, the parameter defaults to StandardError](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_exceptions.html); it looks like `unidecoder` raises kinda other exception, but the stacktrace seems to be incomplete (it should show the exception type.)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at "C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unidecoder-1.1.1/lib/unidecoder/data/x00.yml". Line 2 is an YAML entry `- "\z"`，which is not a valid escape sequence in Ruby(but a Regexp anchor to mark the end of string). This might be a bug. You can edit this line to `- "\x00"`.

However, `"\u00A3"`(£) is not a valid ASCII character, I didn't find the point of encoding it to ASCII.

The exception raised is Psych::SyntaxError, you can catch that specific exception, as @mudasobwa commented.

Comment: I would edit it but I think I've seen as much of unicoder as I'd like to at this point.